# Anylogic - How to implement CRN (Common Random Numbers) method in the simulation experiment?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to implement the CRN method in the Anylogic simulation software, but I don't know how to deal with settings.

What am I understanding is that:

1) I have to create my own custom random number generator.

2) Moreover, after each simulation replication, the specified seed number has to be inputted from coding (Seed numbers will change after each simulation runs).

For instance: My model has​ 5 replications per iteration

Run #1 Seed value = 10

Run #2 Seed value = 20

Run #3 Seed value = 30

Run #4 Seed value = 40

Run #5 Seed value = 50

I will use this setting for two simulation model. 
How do I do the setting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if this will work exactly as intended... but in the randomness section of the experiment properties you can select custom generator and use the following:

```
new Random(10+10*getCurrentReplication())
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to implement the code in my model.

Comment: There was an error when I input the code you have suggested to me.

The error was: The method of getCurrentReplication() is undefined for the type Simulation.
I am sorry to bother you again.... Do you have any suggestion to fix this problem?

Comment: that code is only useful for experiments that allow replications... if you use the simulation type, then you can't use replications.... experiments with replications are for example parameter variation or monte carlo...

Comment: Ah, yes, there was no error when applying the code with parameter variation experiment. I am so sorry for my misunderstanding. Thank you very much!